# Xen Hosting - What Could Be Causing My Kernel to Not Boot - At All?

Tags: xen, grub, paravirtualization

I have a VPS at Linode, and I'm trying to boot Gentoo's hardened kernel - which is patched with Grsecurity and PaX.

On Linode, you can boot a kernel of your choice by utilizing their "PV-Grub" kernel; and I have done so successfully a dozen times with Gentoo's stock kernel (e.g. gentoo-sources).

I've carefully documented my process, and I perfectly replicated it. But now that I'm using the hardened kernel, this (inexplicable thing) happens:

[phase one http://www.upl.co/uploads/Screen-Shot-20111109-at-541.png](http://www.upl.co/uploads/Screen-Shot-20111109-at-541.png)
[phase two http://www.upl.co/uploads/Screen-Shot-20111109-at-434.png](http://www.upl.co/uploads/Screen-Shot-20111109-at-434.png)
[phase three http://www.upl.co/uploads/Screen-Shot-20111109-at-433.png](http://www.upl.co/uploads/Screen-Shot-20111109-at-433.png)

I'm at a loss here. I don't know what could be causing this. As Linode's support team puts it:

> " ... while we do give customers the ability to boot into their own custom kernel this is an
>   entirely unsupported configuration and we are unable to provide any configuration assistance
>   or guidance for custom kernel configurations."

I'm hoping someone more versed in Xen than myself can offer some guidance.